# freemarker check if nested list attr exists

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a nested list in freemarker model as:

```
heap:
  A:
    A1: 900
    A2: 900
  B:
    B1: 1000
    B2: 1000
  C:    1200
  D:
    D1: 1300
    D2: 1350
    D3: 1600
```

in the nested list not every attr has child attr, like C: 1200,

results in error with the following template:

```
heap{
  <#list heap as group, attrs>
    <#list attrs as key, value>
      ${group}.${key?right_pad(20) ${value}
    </#list>
  </#lsit>
}
```

"Expected an extended hash, but this has evaluated to a string" error

what would be the correct template to iterate the nested list? Thanks

Comment: The rational of the following is I wanted to interpret it as a string A.A1 900  
${group}.${key?right_pad(20) ${value} =>
A.A1 900
what is the correct syntax for that? 
Based on that, and how to check if the child attrs exits or not?

Comment: The data-model seems to be weird. The best solution would be to fixing that. If `C` has no children, then value in that `Map` should just be an empty `List`. Why is it a string? (You haven't included the full error message, but I guess it refers to `attrs`.)